# Automatic arrangement of equations with comments

Tags: tables, equations, align, automation

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`conteq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/conteq)

I am writing a paper with multiple chains of equations or inequalities, with optional explanations. Depending on the size of the equations, I use one of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Short style:
\begin{align*}
lhs1 &= rhs1 && \text{expl1} \\
     &\le rhs2 \\
     &= rhs3 && \text{expl3}
\end{align*}

Medium style:
\begin{align*}
lhs1 &= rhs1 \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \text{expl1} \\
     &\le rhs2 \\
     &= rhs3 \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \text{expl3}
\end{align*}

Large style:
\begin{align*}
     &\phantom{{}={}} lhs1\\
     &= rhs1 \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \text{expl1} \\
     &\le rhs2 \\
     &= rhs3 \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \text{expl3}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This looks nice, but is not convenient to switch between. So I’d like to have three environments `eqchains`, `eqchainm` and `eqchainl` that produce the appropriate output, given an input in this form:

```
\begin{eqchain?}
lhs1 &= rhs1 & expl1 \\
     \le rhs2 \\
     = rhs3 & expl3 
\end{eqchain?}
```

(Of course, the `&` can be some other symbol). Bonus points if the styling of the explanation can be modified by redefining a macro, e.g. `\newcommand{\eqchainexpl}[1]{\text{\{ \textit{#1} \}}`.

And, if that was possible, I’d like to have an environment `eqchain` that automatically selects the right environment using the following heuristics: If lhs1 and the largest rhs is together smaller than ⅔ of the `\linewith`, use `eqchains`. If the lhs1 and the largest rhs is smaller than the `\linewidth`, use `eqchainm`. Otherwise use `eqchainl`. Final bonus points if the explanation is set in a `\parbox` so that long explanations are wrapped and do not affect the horizontal positioning of the math content.

Comment: Please always make your examples into complete runnable documents (which allows them to be tested (by you and others). Here I _think_ you are missing a `\\ `  after `lhs1` in the "large` example (or you want a layout I find rather strange)

Comment: Added missing `\\` and a document preamble.

Comment: Instead of `\phantom{{}={}}` use `\mathrel{\phantom{=}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems that no existing package was able to provide this feature, I did it myself and created the [`conteq` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/conteq). It does not (yet) do automatic layout selection, but provides a few layout and new ones can easily be added.